# Undefned index year for Jalali calender in Laravel

Tags: laravel, datepicker, jalali-calendar

I want to save date in database. I'm using [Persian_datepicker](http://babakhani.github.io/PersianWebToolkit/doc/datepicker/) package for choosing date and also using [Jalali](https://github.com/morilog/jalali) calendar for converting to gregorian date. But I got the error:

**Error**:

> Undefned index year

**Code**:

```
pdate = "۱۴۰۰/۰۳/۲۹";
\Morilog\Jalali\Jalalian::fromFormat('Y/m/d', $pdate)->toCarbon();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert Persian date to English format and then convert to Gregorian.

۱۴۰۰-۰۳-۲۹ (Persian format) -> 1400-03-29 (English format) -> 2021-06-19 (gregorian)

I used `CalendarUtils` class from Jalali package. Suppose `$date` is "۱۴۰۰-۰۳-۲۹".

**Code**:

```
public function jalaliToCarbon($date)
    {
        $date = CalendarUtils::convertNumbers($date, true);
        $latin_date = CalendarUtils::createCarbonFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)->format('Y-m-d');
        return $latin_date;
    }
```

Comment: hi ,i have a same problem, where use this function?in controller?

Comment: @mahdi.gh, You can use anywhere but It is better to create a class for such functions.